# I got a "'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable" error on Django 3.0 on a Queryset thats returns a list of objects

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, iterable

I'm stuck with a `TypeError: 'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable` error in Django 3.0

Here is my problem:
I have to models `Collection` and `Element` with have a `ManyToMany` relationship.

Here are the models (I obviously omitted all the other attributes and methods which are not related to the problem):

```py
class Collection(models.Models):
   elements = models.ManyToManyField(Element, related_name="collections")

   @proprety
   def total_elements_value(self):
        total = 0
        for element in self.elements.all():  # The problem is on this line !
            total += element.total_value
        return total


class Element(models.Models):
   value1 = models.IntegerField()
   value2 = models.IntegerField()

   @proprety
   def total_value(self):
        return self.value1 + self.value2
```

But when I try to call the Collection.total_elements_value proprety, I got this error:

> TypeError: 'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable

I don't understand. The self.elements.all() return a list as Queryset, so it should be iterable, isn't it ?

When I try this in the python shell, this works fine:

```py
c = Collection.objects.all()[0]

total = 0
for element in c.elements.all():
    total += element.total_value
return total  # Works
```

But not when I call the proprety:

```py
c = Collection.objects.all()[0]
c.total_elements_value  # Throws the error
```

I would like to know how to fix this, but more important, to understand why this doesn't work.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you sure it is `for element in self.elements.all():`, and not `for element in self.elements:`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found out were the problem was.

I my code, I forgot the parentheses in the model definition.
And I put the parentheses in my template tags.

It was the other way around.

Comment: If `Collection.total_elements_value ` is what you called, it's not correct. You're accessing a instance property from the class. `Collection.objects.first().total_elements_value` should work (provided there is at least one collection).

Comment: @Melvyn `c.total_elements_value` was called, which is an Collection instance (`c = Collection.objects.all()[0]`)

Answer (score -1):

As it's stated in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/relations/) the actual set will be accessible by adding `_set` at the end (if you don't manually state otherwise). In your case get QuerySet of all realted objects with `self.elements_set.all()`